# simplify a tikz sample

Tags: tikz-pgf

I redraw as a test a sample of a grafic that i found online with tikz.
now it got a bit complicated and im interested in a different possible solution. Maybe less text maybe with other specialityies.

this is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%Font settings
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}

%Support for German
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.8, yscale=0.8,]
  %( left lower edge ) rectangle (right top edge) node[anchor=center] at (x,y in rectangle)  
    \filldraw[ fill=green!20, align=center, thick, rounded corners=2pt,]
      (-1.8,2.9) rectangle (5.1,1.7) node[anchor=center] at (1.7,2.25)  
      { <header> \\ \footnotesize contains the brandings like logo };
    \filldraw[fill=green!20, align=center, thick, rounded corners=2pt,]
      (-1.8,0.3) rectangle (5.1,1.55) node[anchor=center] at (1.7,0.9)
      { <nav> \\ \footnotesize contains navigational section of the site };
    \filldraw[fill=green!20, align=center, thick, rounded corners=2pt,]
      (-1.8,-3.1) rectangle (2.2,0.2) node[anchor=center] at (0.2,-0.5)
      {\footnotesize <article> \\ \tiny web page main content };
    \filldraw[fill=green!10, align=center, thin, rounded corners=2pt,]
      (-1.7,-2) rectangle (2.1,-1) node[anchor=center] at (0.2,-1.48)
      {\footnotesize <section> \\ \tiny divided section of main content }; 
    \filldraw[fill=green!10, align=center, thin, rounded corners=2pt,]
      (-1.7,-3) rectangle (2.1,-2.1) node[anchor=center] at (0.2,-2.55)
      {\footnotesize <section> \\ \tiny divided section of main content };
    \filldraw[fill=green!20, align=center, thick, rounded corners=2pt,]
      (2.3,-3.1) rectangle (5.1,0.2) node[anchor=center] at (3.7,-0.8)
      { <aside> \\ \tiny contains extra information \\ \tiny and related content or links };
    \filldraw[ fill=green!20, align=center, thick, rounded corners=2pt,]
      (-1.8,-4.3) rectangle (5.1,-3.2) node[anchor=center] at (1.7,-3.8)  
      { <footer> \\ \tiny infomation about copyright, privacy policy, terms of use, etc... };  
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Couple of points: Have a look at the positioning library, that makes arrangement easier. It may make sense to define colours like "main" "secondary" outside of the tikzpicture so that can change the colour scheme if necessary (Equally, use that have a consistent colour scheme across your document without backtracking to a particular environment that uses the colour.)

Comment: A `different possible solution` depends on what you want and you don't say it. And `Maybe less text maybe with other specialityies` doesn't help. Could you better explain what you want to get and why did you take this base?

Comment: this is my first graphic and i wold like to know if i use the right objects to build a graphic like that or if its maybe easyser with other possibilities(objects like \draw \node rectangle or what ever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about easier, but shorter... yes.  See how I replaced the first command with `\dosmth` that is shorter.  You can do the same for the remaining commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
%Font settings
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}

%Support for German
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\dosmth}[7]{\filldraw[style=mystyle] (#1,#2) rectangle (#3,#4) node[anchor=center] at (#5,#6) {#7};}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{mystyle} = [ fill=green!20, align=center, thick, rounded corners=2pt,]
  \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.8, yscale=0.8,]
  %( left lower edge ) rectangle (right top edge) node[anchor=center] at (x,y in rectangle)  
  \dosmth{-1.8}{2.9}{5.1}{1.7}{1.7}{2.25}{ <header> \\ \footnotesize contains the brandings like logo };
    \filldraw[style=mystyle]
      (-1.8,0.3) rectangle (5.1,1.55) node[anchor=center] at (1.7,0.9)
      { <nav> \\ \footnotesize contains navigational section of the site };
    \filldraw[style=mystyle]
      (-1.8,-3.1) rectangle (2.2,0.2) node[anchor=center] at (0.2,-0.5)
      {\footnotesize <article> \\ \tiny web page main content };
    \filldraw[style=mystyle]
      (-1.7,-2) rectangle (2.1,-1) node[anchor=center] at (0.2,-1.48)
      {\footnotesize <section> \\ \tiny divided section of main content }; 
    \filldraw[style=mystyle]
      (-1.7,-3) rectangle (2.1,-2.1) node[anchor=center] at (0.2,-2.55)
      {\footnotesize <section> \\ \tiny divided section of main content };
    \filldraw[style=mystyle]
      (2.3,-3.1) rectangle (5.1,0.2) node[anchor=center] at (3.7,-0.8)
      { <aside> \\ \tiny contains extra information \\ \tiny and related content or links };
    \filldraw[style=mystyle]
      (-1.8,-4.3) rectangle (5.1,-3.2) node[anchor=center] at (1.7,-3.8)  
      { <footer> \\ \tiny infomation about copyright, privacy policy, terms of use, etc... };  
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: ah thats quite a bit easier shortend like that! thanks. 
I was wondering also if it wold be possible to just center the text in the rectangle instead as defining absolute coordinates...?